# How to improve performance of queries which use table-valued functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT a.id, b.colb, c.colc, d.cold, ...
FROM a JOIN b on a.id=b.id
       JOIN c on a.id=c.id
       JOIN d on a.id=d.id
       JOIN e on a.id=e.id
       ...
```

Each table here is actually a table-valued function. Runtime of this query is more than a minute, but when I manually create temporary tables (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ax as SELECT * from a`) and run the query against those, it takes milliseconds (and creating the tables takes milliseconds too).

What could be causing this large performance difference (at least two orders of magnitude)?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could show your PostgreSQL version and the output of `explain analyze` on your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PostgreSQL optimizer might choose to execute your joins as a [loop join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aJoin_algorithms).  That is, it would evaluate the function call for each left-hand row.

Your solution with temporary tables is an excellent way to avoid that.  Even if the optimizer would prefer the `loop join` again, the result would be a lot of lookups in the temporary table.  Lookups are an order of magnitude cheaper than repeated evaluation of a function.

Comment: Is that the case even if the function has been marked as STABLE (i.e. shouldn't need to be repeatedly evaluated)?

Comment: STABLE just says the function only has to be evaluated once for the same set of values.  It might still be necessary to evaluate it once per row.  Since you are able to pre-fetch the function's result, that suggest your function is less volatile than stable, and does not depend on any row.  STABLE does not tell the optimizer all that.

Answer (score 1):

Try CTEs:

```
with
    a as (select * from a),
    b as (select * from b),
    c as (select * from c),
    d as (select * from d),
    e as (select * from e)
select a.id, b.colb, c.colc, d.cold, ...
from a
    join b on a.id=b.id
    join c on a.id=c.id
    join d on a.id=d.id
    join e on a.id=e.id
```